# Keycloak and icCube - stuck in a redirect loop - what is wrong?

Tags: keycloak, iccube

I am trying to use `Keycloak` in front of `icCube` and encounter a redirect loop.

**Done so far:**

- installed `icCube` on a Linux - Debian 10 system, 8Gb as a Virtual Machine in VMWare (following advice in https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/running_iccube/server_linux.php)
- created two roles: `IC3_admin` (all access) and `IC3_sales` (access to cube sales)
- changed `icCube.xml` in accordance with https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/authentication_keycloak.php
- icCube/console is activated
- installed keycloak on the same server

with regard to keycloak:

- created Realm icCube and client iccube, with 2 users: admin and user
- created 2 roles: admin and sales

the client iccube is:

- root URL: http://192.168.178.32:8282
- valid redirect uri's: "/icCube/doc/ic3report" and "/icCube/console"

the json file is:

```
  {
  "realm": "icCube",
  "auth-server-url": "http://192.168.178.32:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "iccube",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": ".... secret ...."
  },
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "policy-enforcer": {}
}
```

When I logon to "http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console" I get a non-icCube logon whcih I use to login with the Keycloak/iccube account "admin" (see above).

As a result I get a very long URL and in Firefox the message: "The page isn’t redirecting properly".

The icCube log gives multiple DEBUG statements with AUTHENTICATED:

```
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.635 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.635 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.635 CEST) there was no code
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.635 CEST) redirecting to auth server
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.635 CEST) callback uri: http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.635 CEST) [keycloak] challenge
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.635 CEST) Sending redirect to login page: http://192.168.178.32:8080/auth/realms/icCube%20-%20IAH/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=iccube&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.178.32%3A8282%2FicCube%2Fconsole&state=d640ddd7-a711-4b7e-b5ce-3ae0f53b43f7&login=true&scope=openid
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.681 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.681 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=d640ddd7-a711-4b7e-b5ce-3ae0f53b43f7&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=af0c087a-ef4f-4ae0-9135-65b0b4e3a38f.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.681 CEST) there was a code, resolving
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.681 CEST) checking state cookie for after code
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.681 CEST) ** reseting application state cookie
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.691 CEST) Verifying tokens
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.692 CEST) Token Verification succeeded!
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.692 CEST) successful authenticated
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.693 CEST) Adding mapping (bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63, 87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685, node01jxe0ttz3kb2e17wughjmvkqwd4)
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.693 CEST) User '87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685' invoking 'http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=d640ddd7-a711-4b7e-b5ce-3ae0f53b43f7&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=af0c087a-ef4f-4ae0-9135-65b0b4e3a38f.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90' on client 'iccube'
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.693 CEST) AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.693 CEST) [keycloak] AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.710 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.711 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.711 CEST) there was no code
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.712 CEST) redirecting to auth server
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.712 CEST) callback uri: http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.712 CEST) [keycloak] challenge
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.713 CEST) Sending redirect to login page: http://192.168.178.32:8080/auth/realms/icCube%20-%20IAH/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=iccube&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.178.32%3A8282%2FicCube%2Fconsole&state=463775c9-0f3b-40af-82c2-7f629e0b8450&login=true&scope=openid
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.750 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.750 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=463775c9-0f3b-40af-82c2-7f629e0b8450&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=1b68dcf1-93bb-419b-b221-250ccf1e06c7.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.750 CEST) there was a code, resolving
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.750 CEST) checking state cookie for after code
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.750 CEST) ** reseting application state cookie
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.764 CEST) Verifying tokens
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.765 CEST) Token Verification succeeded!
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.765 CEST) successful authenticated
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.765 CEST) Adding mapping (bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63, 87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685, node01jxe0ttz3kb2e17wughjmvkqwd4)
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.765 CEST) User '87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685' invoking 'http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=463775c9-0f3b-40af-82c2-7f629e0b8450&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=1b68dcf1-93bb-419b-b221-250ccf1e06c7.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90' on client 'iccube'
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.765 CEST) AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.765 CEST) [keycloak] AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.785 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.785 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.785 CEST) there was no code
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.785 CEST) redirecting to auth server
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.785 CEST) callback uri: http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.785 CEST) [keycloak] challenge
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.785 CEST) Sending redirect to login page: http://192.168.178.32:8080/auth/realms/icCube%20-%20IAH/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=iccube&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.178.32%3A8282%2FicCube%2Fconsole&state=59391636-dc93-4677-bce2-e2084d0eb72f&login=true&scope=openid
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.826 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.826 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=59391636-dc93-4677-bce2-e2084d0eb72f&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=a53cd244-a2b0-4227-ac72-8f202423f4d4.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.826 CEST) there was a code, resolving
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.826 CEST) checking state cookie for after code
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.826 CEST) ** reseting application state cookie
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.839 CEST) Verifying tokens
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.840 CEST) Token Verification succeeded!
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.840 CEST) successful authenticated
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.840 CEST) Adding mapping (bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63, 87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685, node01jxe0ttz3kb2e17wughjmvkqwd4)
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.840 CEST) User '87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685' invoking 'http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=59391636-dc93-4677-bce2-e2084d0eb72f&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=a53cd244-a2b0-4227-ac72-8f202423f4d4.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90' on client 'iccube'
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.841 CEST) AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.841 CEST) [keycloak] AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.857 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.858 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.858 CEST) there was no code
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.858 CEST) redirecting to auth server
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.858 CEST) callback uri: http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.858 CEST) [keycloak] challenge
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.858 CEST) Sending redirect to login page: http://192.168.178.32:8080/auth/realms/icCube%20-%20IAH/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=iccube&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.178.32%3A8282%2FicCube%2Fconsole&state=1cc7503b-80fb-435b-b744-171aa06c3b39&login=true&scope=openid
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.897 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.897 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=1cc7503b-80fb-435b-b744-171aa06c3b39&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=550019b0-3e57-44c4-aec2-91830305cd05.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.897 CEST) there was a code, resolving
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.897 CEST) checking state cookie for after code
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.897 CEST) ** reseting application state cookie
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.909 CEST) Verifying tokens
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.909 CEST) Token Verification succeeded!
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.909 CEST) successful authenticated
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.909 CEST) Adding mapping (bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63, 87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685, node01jxe0ttz3kb2e17wughjmvkqwd4)
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.909 CEST) User '87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685' invoking 'http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=1cc7503b-80fb-435b-b744-171aa06c3b39&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=550019b0-3e57-44c4-aec2-91830305cd05.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90' on client 'iccube'
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.909 CEST) AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.909 CEST) [keycloak] AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.925 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.925 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.926 CEST) there was no code
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.926 CEST) redirecting to auth server
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.926 CEST) callback uri: http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.926 CEST) [keycloak] challenge
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.926 CEST) Sending redirect to login page: http://192.168.178.32:8080/auth/realms/icCube%20-%20IAH/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=iccube&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.178.32%3A8282%2FicCube%2Fconsole&state=4a3c9e3f-226b-4c6e-ab16-776a8154c814&login=true&scope=openid
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.965 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.965 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=4a3c9e3f-226b-4c6e-ab16-776a8154c814&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=e4518c30-e110-4ab2-8eed-f1c9d2fe9cca.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.965 CEST) there was a code, resolving
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.965 CEST) checking state cookie for after code
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.965 CEST) ** reseting application state cookie
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.983 CEST) Verifying tokens
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.984 CEST) Token Verification succeeded!
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.984 CEST) successful authenticated
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.984 CEST) Adding mapping (bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63, 87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685, node01jxe0ttz3kb2e17wughjmvkqwd4)
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.984 CEST) User '87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685' invoking 'http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=4a3c9e3f-226b-4c6e-ab16-776a8154c814&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=e4518c30-e110-4ab2-8eed-f1c9d2fe9cca.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90' on client 'iccube'
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.984 CEST) AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:38.984 CEST) [keycloak] AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.007 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.007 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.007 CEST) there was no code
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.007 CEST) redirecting to auth server
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.007 CEST) callback uri: http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.007 CEST) [keycloak] challenge
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.007 CEST) Sending redirect to login page: http://192.168.178.32:8080/auth/realms/icCube%20-%20IAH/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=iccube&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.178.32%3A8282%2FicCube%2Fconsole&state=15f5d3cd-6f6b-4c73-80a6-6ed094fed4b9&login=true&scope=openid
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.046 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.046 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=15f5d3cd-6f6b-4c73-80a6-6ed094fed4b9&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=df2f1d13-3083-496e-95a9-128f0455b7c6.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.046 CEST) there was a code, resolving
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.046 CEST) checking state cookie for after code
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.046 CEST) ** reseting application state cookie
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.058 CEST) Verifying tokens
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.059 CEST) Token Verification succeeded!
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.059 CEST) successful authenticated
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.059 CEST) Adding mapping (bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63, 87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685, node01jxe0ttz3kb2e17wughjmvkqwd4)
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.059 CEST) User '87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685' invoking 'http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=15f5d3cd-6f6b-4c73-80a6-6ed094fed4b9&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=df2f1d13-3083-496e-95a9-128f0455b7c6.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90' on client 'iccube'
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.059 CEST) AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.059 CEST) [keycloak] AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.082 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.082 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.082 CEST) there was no code
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.082 CEST) redirecting to auth server
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.082 CEST) callback uri: http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.082 CEST) [keycloak] challenge
[               qtp689602108-24] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.082 CEST) Sending redirect to login page: http://192.168.178.32:8080/auth/realms/icCube%20-%20IAH/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=iccube&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.178.32%3A8282%2FicCube%2Fconsole&state=c9ed05ce-bc2f-4a19-ae8c-b076065f7bfc&login=true&scope=openid
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.117 CEST) [keycloak] Keycloak OIDC Filter
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.117 CEST) adminRequest http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=c9ed05ce-bc2f-4a19-ae8c-b076065f7bfc&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=9e424234-efd2-40e7-a23b-97f1a0e035a4.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.117 CEST) there was a code, resolving
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.117 CEST) checking state cookie for after code
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.117 CEST) ** reseting application state cookie
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.126 CEST) Verifying tokens
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.127 CEST) Token Verification succeeded!
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.127 CEST) successful authenticated
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.127 CEST) Adding mapping (bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63, 87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685, node01jxe0ttz3kb2e17wughjmvkqwd4)
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.127 CEST) User '87fd7de0-430e-4c2c-bcfe-eeafd6525685' invoking 'http://192.168.178.32:8282/icCube/console?state=c9ed05ce-bc2f-4a19-ae8c-b076065f7bfc&session_state=bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63&code=9e424234-efd2-40e7-a23b-97f1a0e035a4.bbdc1239-45fa-4dd3-a53e-548fcec11b63.2dfad5fc-49a7-438f-a09f-e06a174efc90' on client 'iccube'
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.127 CEST) AUTHENTICATED
[               qtp689602108-25] [DEBUG] (13-07-19 15:16:39.127 CEST) [keycloak] AUTHENTICATED
```

What is wrong with the keycloak configuration (or is something else fishy)?

Answer (score 0):

More like a question for Keycloak configuration; I believe the valid url is wrong: guess you can try * instead.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I want to share the the right settings that worked for me. Although I am not 100% sure, I guess the "Direct Access Grants enabled" did the trick. For all my settings see enclosed image.

[image: settings for keycloak]